# How to create a stream with Scalaz-Stream?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz-stream

It must be damn simple. But for some reason I cannot make it work.

- If I do `io.linesR(...)`, I have a stream of lines of the file, it's ok.
- If I do `Processor.emitAll()`, I have a stream of pre-defined values. It also works.

But what I actually need is to produce values for scalaz-stream asynchronously (well, from Akka actor).

I have tried:

- `async.unboundedQueue[String]`
- `async.signal[String]`

Then called `queue.enqueueOne(...).run` or `signal.set(...).run` and listened to `queue.dequeue` or `signal.discrete`. Just with `.map` and `.to`. With an example proved to work with another kind of stream -- either with Processor or lines from the file.

What is the secret? What is the preferred way to create a channel to be streamed later? How to feed it with values from another context?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the approach described here: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream/blob/master/src/test/scala/scalaz/stream/examples/CreatingStreams.scala#L85. Paul is also providing this gist on the subject: https://gist.github.com/pchiusano/8087426

Answer (score 0):

If the values are produced asynchronously but in a way that can be driven from the stream, I've found it easiest to use the "primitive" `await` method and construct the process "by hand". You need an indirectly recursive function:

```
def processStep(v: Int): Process[Future, Int] =
  Process.emit(v) ++ Process.await(myActor ? NextValuePlease())(w => processStep(w))
```

But if you need a truly async process, driven from elsewhere, I've never done that.

Comment: I really need a truly async process. I have master/workers actors topology with unpredictable delays for requests (up to hours), and I need to write the events to the file line by line. Don't know how to employ your snippet there :( but I'll take a look this direction, thanks